# Issue With Same Inbox Subject as Multiple Objects

Tags: python, django

I'm using this [Django Messages](https://github.com/arneb/django-messages) package. Messages in the inbox with the same subject keeps showing up more than once depending on the number of times a sender and the recipient receives messages. I want a situation whereby messages with the same subject will only show up once in the inbox and not twice or thrice.

[image]

I've looked into the code and I did this

```
 message_list = Message.objects.inbox_for(request.user).values('subject').distinct()
```

But still not working.

```
{% for message in message_list %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ message.sender|capfirst }}</td>
    <td>
      {% if message.new %}<strong>{% endif %}
        {% if message.replied %}<em>{% endif %}
        <a href="{{message.get_absolute_url }}">{{ message.subject }}</a>
        {% if message.replied %}</em>{% endif %}
        {% if message.new %}</strong>{% endif %}
    </td>
    <td>{{ message.sent_at|date:_("DATETIME_FORMAT") }} </td>
   {# <td><a href="{% url 'messages_delete' message.id %}">{% trans "delete" %}</a></td>#}
  </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

UPDATED:

```
{% ifchanged message.subject %}
      <a href="{{message.get_absolute_url }}">{{ message.subject }}</a>
{% else %}
  <a href="{{message.get_absolute_url }}">{{ message.subject }}</a>
{% endifchanged %}
```

Comment: One of those subjects is in italics, the other is not.  So presumably they are registering as different subjects.

Comment: yeah that's true. It seems the one with the italic is the 'replied msg', like a reply from a sender. Kindly check my question for updated question.

Answer (score 0):

The `Message` model also includes an `ordering`, which will be included in the `distinct` call and make those rows distinct. See the first note on the [distinct documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#distinct).

If you are using PostgreSQL, you can use:

```
messages.order_by('subject', '-sent_at').distinct('subject')
```

Another option is to forget the `distinct` and use the [`ifchanged` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged):

```
{% ifchanged message.subject %}
    ... code to display message ...
{% endifchanged %}
```

This will be a problem if you want to display a certain number of messages.

---

I had elided most of the detail before, but given your update, a bit more clear:

```
{% for message in message_list %}
  {% ifchanged message.subject %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ message.sender|capfirst }}</td>
    <td>
      {% if message.new %}<strong>{% endif %}
        {% if message.replied %}<em>{% endif %}
        <a href="{{message.get_absolute_url }}">{{ message.subject }}</a>
        {% if message.replied %}</em>{% endif %}
        {% if message.new %}</strong>{% endif %}
    </td>
    <td>{{ message.sent_at|date:_("DATETIME_FORMAT") }} </td>
   {# <td><a href="{% url 'messages_delete' message.id %}">{% trans "delete" %}</a></td>#}
  </tr>
  {% endifchanged %}
{% endfor %}
```

You need to put the `ifchanged` tags immediately inside the `for` loop.

Comment: Can you edit the question and add your code with `ifchanged`?

Comment: Kindly check the updated question. If not changed.. then show me a new message.

Comment: I edited my answer. You need to put the `ifchanged` tag immediately after the `for` loop, so everything inside only appears if the subject is changed. There is a disadvantage with this method: the messages will only be hidden if they are adjacent. Then again, the PostgreSQL only method forced you to order messages by subject, which you might not want to do. An alternative is to fetch the objects and do the filtering in Python.